# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lsxbe (Not found in java.library.path)

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I try to use Lotus Notes API in java but i receive the error in object.
This is the code:

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class HelloTest extends NotesThread {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        HelloTest t = new HelloTest();
        t.start();
    }
    public void runNotes() {
       try{
           Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();
           // To bypass Readers fields restrictions
           Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
           String p = s.getPlatform();
           System.out.println("Platform = " + p);
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Post the stack trace

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lsxbe (Not found in java.library.path)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1217)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1181)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:530)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.initThread(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to add the paths to notes' installation folder e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes` and notes' user data folder e.g. `C:\Lotus\Notes\Data` to your environment variable `PATH`
2. Use a x32-JRE (For compatibility with the Notes DLLs)
3. Call `lotus.notes.NotesThread.sinitThread();` before `Session s = NotesFactory.createSession();`

Answer (score 0):

This error typically shows that the API you are using requires a native library, that has to be loaded by the runtime. The native libraries are distributed together with the API jar. Is there anything like this mentioned in the Lotus notes documentation?

Native libraries are loaded with a single method call: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)

This call should made before any calls to the API. I suggest you can put it as the first line of your main() method.

Comment: This is a quote from a official tutorial: Java application that makes local Domino calls must contain Domino Server, Domino Designer, or Notes Client, and must include Notes.jar in the classpath. Have you got this up and running?